# Regex to match name permutation

Tags: regex, database, oracle, permutation

Suppose, I have names like

1. GREAT KING JOHN
2. KING JOHN GREAT
3. JOHN GREAT

in my Oracle database. I am looking for a **REGEX** which will match the **first two** and **not** the **third one** (1. GREAT KING JOHN, 2. KING JOHN GREAT).
That is the **REGEX** should be able to match the exact permutation of the names.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT in your title!

Comment: Are you sure a regex is the right way to go about this?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler am not sure if regex is the right way . if there are other ways of doing it could you please suggest me ?

Comment: You need to provide more information. A regular expression will only work if there is some pattern to the names, i.e. you want to match where there are 3 names and not 2? What characterises the set of names you do want to match?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I see that Oracle doesn't support positive lookahead. I guess that this won't work for you. Sorry.

---

I think the best way to do this is a lookahead on each keyword, if oracle supports it. Pipes create the possible problem of matching things like `JOHN JOHN JOHN` or `GREAT GREAT JOHN`

```
^(?=.*GREAT.*)(?=.*KING.*)(?=.*JOHN.*).+$
```

Comment: thanks but king john great was only an example there are thousands of other names with the same pattern.. i need a regex which would match all such names ...